# Как запустить сайт, что дальше после верстки?

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование

я новичок. Взял готовый дизайн код для сайта. Я его сверстал, html+css+js, адапатировал. Теперь у меня есть готовый код. Но какие действия дальше? Нужно превратить верстку во что? Сайт простой из одной страницы. То есть готов изучать, платить за хостинг и тд, но не представляю что нужно для этого. WordPress?

Comment: Запустить веб-сервер, настроив его на раздачу вашей одной страницы, и поделиться адресом веб-сервера с народом

Comment: Нужно прежде всего научиться пользоваться поисковыми системами.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно зарегистрироваться у любого провайдера хостинга, который оказывает услугу shared-хостинга. Доменное имя можно купить у того же провайдера. Осмотритесь в личном кабинете хостинга. Освойте базовые манипуляции с сайтом и настройки. Среди прочего в личном кабинете будет функционал для того, чтобы залить файлы вашего сайта на хостинг. Когда зальете, ваш сайт станет доступен неограниченному кругу лиц по имени домена примерно через несколько часов.

Comment: А заливать что? Html или php?

Comment: Заливать всё, что там у вас имеется. Если у вас 'html+css+js' то откуда тут взяться php? Если весь сайт -ваша страничка - свёрстана в виде одного файла - его и грузите. Если же в html подключены css и js в виде отдельных файлов - грузите на хостинг их все. Включая файлы картинок, если таковые имеются.

Comment: То есть, если у меня простой лендинг и только форма работающая на js, то всё будет работать(в теории), в том числе мне смогут на емейл писать люди? Выходит я просто загружаю всё, что есть(верстку в виде html,ccs+js) и ничего более не нужно?(ну соответственно править я только через код смогу текст). Спасибо за ответ заранее.

Comment: @Алекс, то есть надо залить всё на хостинг, запустить и опробовать. Если локально всё работает, возможно сразу заработает и на хостинге. Впрочем, если вы у себя использовали какие-то сторонние библиотеки, то их необходимо и на хостинге подключить. Если же не заработает сразу, что вы там написали, смотрите логи ошибок и исправляйте. Порой на хостинге сразу из коробки включены не все модули php, например. Едва ли javascript лично отправляет письма. Скорее, он обрабатывает форму и передаёт её php-скрипту. Значит и php у вас есть, а это уже другая история.

Answer (score 0):

Ну, если сайт будет статичным, то не надо его ни во что "превращать". Достаточно оплатить хостинг, тот выдаст вам данные для подключения по FTP, через какую-нибудь Filezilla заливаете туда все и готово.